# C++ Program requires me to input twice even though the variable gets assigned the first time

Tags: c++, cin

Every time I try to input my answer it requires me to input it twice. Even though examScore1 already gets assigned a value the first time, it still requires me to put in another value. I designed the program so that if anything that is not a number is entered it will output an error message, and ask the user to input again one time, and then the program will end completely.

```
 cout << "Please enter score for Exam 1: ";
        cin >> examScore1;
        if(!(cin >> examScore1)||!(examScore1 <= 100 || examScore1 >= 0))
        {
            cout << "Exam score cannot be less than 0 or more than 100" << endl;
            cout << "Please re-enter score for Exam 1: \n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cin >> examScore1;
            if(!(cin >> examScore1)||!(examScore1 <= 100 || examScore1 >= 0))
            {
                cout << "\nInvalid input entered. PROGRAM WILL END. Please\n"
                     << "consult the user manual and restart the program\n";
                validInput = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you have `cin >> examScore1;` and next line `if(!(cin >> examScore1)`, so you're asking two times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code i guess that you want user to input `score` range from 0 to 100, and if the user input an invalid one, your program only permit one more input and then exit if the user input an invalide once again. Regarding your question about why your code asking for more input i will try to explain it briefly here.

```
cout << "Please enter score for Exam 1: ";
cin >> examScore1;
```

Here your code asking for an input and then put it into `examScore1`. After that

```
if(!(cin >> examScore1)||!(examScore1 <= 100 || examScore1 >= 0))
```

i think you want to check it, but hold on a second. In the very first statement

```
!(cin >> examScore1)
```

You want more input, this is why your code keep asking for an input even after you input the score. If you only want to check it, just do it like this

```
if(examScore1 > 100 || examScore1 < 0){
    //Tell the user that the score is wrong
}
```

After that, you want to give the user once more chance to input. In your code

```
cout << "Exam score cannot be less than 0 or more than 100" << endl;
cout << "Please re-enter score for Exam 1: \n";
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cin >> examScore1;
if(!(cin >> examScore1)||!(examScore1 <= 100 || examScore1 >= 0))
{
    cout << "\nInvalid input entered. PROGRAM WILL END. Please\n"
         << "consult the user manual and restart the program\n";
    validInput = false;
}
```

Wow dude, calm down :). You just want them to input another one. Just asked them nicely.

```
cout << "Please input score in range (0-100)";
cin >> examScore1;
if(examScore1 > 100 || examScore1 < 0){
    cout << "Wow dude, read the doc please";
}
```

End in the end, your code just look more nicely like this one

```
cout << "Please enter score for Exam 1: ";
cin >> examScore1;
if(examScore1 > 100 || examScore1 < 0){
    cout << "Please input score in range (0-100)";
    cin >> examScore1;
    if(examScore1 > 100 || examScore1 < 0){
        cout << "Wow dude, read the doc please";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I used (!(cin >> examScore1) is because i wanted to deal with letters as well as numbers.

Comment: You can throw exception for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are asking for cin multiple times.
First you cin your value cin >> examScore1;
No problem there.
However in your if, you write if(!(cin >> examScore1))
Which is essentially asking the computer to read the value from console again. The correct way of doing it would be if(!examScore1),

Also, what are you trying to achieve with the if(!(cin >> examScore1))?

Comment: I use if(!(cin >> examScore1) just in case if a letter was entered or anything that wouldn't fit into an int variable.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well that wont give you the result you are after. Is this for a class or something. Because I can give you a quick function that can do what you want.